# How to use string resources in html files

Tags: javascript, html, resources

I am wondering if there is a way to load texts in a website from an external file. After googleing a lot I came up with nothing, but I don't think I am inventing the wheel here.

I need something like

```
<p id="1">Resource.text1</p>
<p id="2">Resource.text2</p>
<p id="3">Resource.text3</p> where locally it looks like this:
<p id="3">Make text <span style="color:blue;">blue</span></p>
```

I am using html with javascript for the frontend, and php for the backend.

Thanks

Comment: If you use PHP for the backend, then why don't you just generate the HTML from PHP?

Comment: @Daniel how is my question a duplicate of what you are referring to?

Comment: you are trying to include text in another html document.

Comment: But not a whole html page, just "part of it"